# Is it possible to compile iPhone app via command-line gcc?

Tags: ios, gcc

If i want to compile minimum OSX app via command-line gcc i can compile the file `test.m`:

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
int main( int argc, char** argv ) { return 0; }
```

via following command:

```
gcc -c test.m
```

But how to compile iOS app same way? I change `test.m` to refer iOS cocoa touch:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
int main( int argc, char** argv ) { return 0; }
```

And this is no longer compiles with error:

```
test.m:1:24: error: UIKit/UIKit.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use xcodebuild if you're building apps from the command line, as they consist of more than just Objective-C files.

Comment: Yes, i know about xcodebuild, but it requires xcode project file and i need to compile single source code file.

Comment: So how about looking at the transcripts from a typical Xcode build? At a guess, it's `-isysroot /Xcode42/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk` that would help, but the command line is quite long.